# webapi occured 405 error in php(and perl)

Tags: php, perl, post, http-post

I have an WEB API and Perl language example code for this API.
I want to use this API in PHP.
However, 405 error occurs.

API document(only LOGIN)

```
JSON文字列
FIELD   TYPE    
*username   String  
*password   String  
*rememberMe String
```

example perl code

```
use strict;
use DBI;
use LWP::UserAgent;

#認証
my $auth_api = 'http://testapi.com/api';
my $username = 'user';
my $password = 'pass';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->parse_head(0);

#ログイン
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $auth_api);
$req->content_type('application/json');
$req->content('{'
.'"username":"'.$username.'",'
.'"password":"'.$password.'" '
.'}');
my $res = $ua->request($req);

#トークン取得
my $csrf_access_token = '';
my $access_token_cookie = '';
my $cookie = "";
if($res->is_success) {
    print $res->content;
    print $res->as_string;
    $cookie = $res->header('set-cookie');
    my @cookies = split(/,|;/, $cookie);
    while (my $c = shift @cookies){
        my ($key, $value) = split(/=/, $c);
        if($key =~ /csrf_access_token/){
            $csrf_access_token = $value;
        }
        if($key =~ /access_token_cookie/){
            $access_token_cookie = $value;
        }
    }
}
else {
    print $res->status_line, "\n";
    print $res->content, "\n";
}

print '"'.$csrf_access_token.'"',"\n";
print '"'.$access_token_cookie.'"',"\n";

#検索url
my $search_api = 'http://testapi.com/api';
my $img_url = 'https://test.com/pics/';
my $num_result = '10';

#トークンを使ってアクセスする
if($csrf_access_token ne ''){
    my $req2 = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $search_api);
    my $shinaban1 = 'g3717380';
    open(my $out, '>out_search.tab');

    $req2->content_type('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    $req2->header("Cookie"=>"access_token_cookie=$access_token_cookie; csrf_access_token=$csrf_access_token");
    $req2->content(
     'img_url='.$img_url.lc($shinaban1).'.jpg'.'&'
    .'num_result='.$num_result.''
    );
    print $req2->as_string;
    my $res = $ua->request($req2);
    if($res->is_success) {
        print $out $res->content;
        print $res->content;
    }
    else {
    print $res->headers_as_string;
        print $res->status_line, "\n";
        print $res->content, "\n";
    }

}
```

example perl code run result

```
C:\Users\TEST>perl search.pl
{"msg":"Login successful","status":200}
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 30 Aug 2018 08:47:16 GMT
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 40
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Authorization,X-CSRF-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://testapi.com
Client-Date: Thu, 30 Aug 2018 08:46:19 GMT
Client-Peer: .........:8080
Client-Response-Num: 1
Set-Cookie: access_token_cookie=qBchXPttiGHhFDuXhi5pQjqN89LTleivPZwQ4eC0; HttpOnly; Path=/api/
Set-Cookie: csrf_access_token=f32a..........388d; Path=/

{"msg":"Login successful","status":200}
"............."
"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q............."
POST http://testapi.com/api
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: access_token_cookie=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC....4eC0; csrf_access_token=f32a5c82-3a44-44

img_url=https://testapi.com/apig3717380.jpg&num_result=10
{
    "status": 0,
    "total_time": 235,
    "preprocess_time": 11,
    "get_feature_time": 99,
    "calculate_euclide": 0,
    "load_embeddings": 0,
    "find_max": 0,
    "sort_min": 0,
    "post_process_img": "/9j/4AAQSkZCAgUEBAMEBgUGBBggLDAsKDAkKCgr/2wBDAQICAgICAZ",
    "response": [
        {
            "id": 113677,
            "name": "test",
            "shban1": "ZO413",
            "distance": "0.22493",
            "url": "https://.......",
            "index": 0
        },
        ...
        {
            "id": 807506,
            "name": "DT039",
            "shinaban1": "G08327",
            "distance": "0.28992",
            "url": "https://...............",
            "index": 9
        }
    ]
}
```

my php code(only login part)

```
$url = 'http://testapi.com/api';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
$rememberMe = true;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json'));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

my php code run result

```
>>> $ch = curl_init();
=> curl resource #481
>>> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
=> true
>>> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
=> true
>>> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json'));
=> true
>>> $output = curl_exec($ch);
{
    "message": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL."
}
=> true
```

webapi url info

```
 >>> $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
 => [
 "url" => "http://testapi.com/api",
 "content_type" => "application/json",
 "http_code" => 405,
 "header_size" => 415,
 "request_size" => 163,
 "filetime" => -1,
 "ssl_verify_result" => 0,
 "redirect_count" => 0,
 "total_time" => 0.187,
 "namelookup_time" => 0.125,
 "connect_time" => 0.156,
 "pretransfer_time" => 0.156,
 "size_upload" => 0.0,
 "size_download" => 70.0,
 "speed_download" => 374.0,
 "speed_upload" => 0.0,
 "download_content_length" => 70.0,
 "upload_content_length" => -1.0,
 "starttransfer_time" => 0.172,
 "redirect_time" => 0.0,
 "redirect_url" => "",
 "primary_ip" => "..........",
 "certinfo" => [],
 "primary_port" => 8080,
 "local_ip" => "............",
 "local_port" => 5544,
 ]
```

I don't know anything about Perl.
What's wrong my PHP code? why occur 405 error?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What does the request look like in the webserver logs? It looks like the PHP code is missing the request method

Comment: It also misses the second step. The Perl code makes two requests. It first fetches a token, and then passes that token as a cookie in the second request. I suggest you go through the Perl code line by line and write down (or create a flowchart) on paper the steps the code does. Then you can redo that in PHP. (The `while` loop goes through all the cookies in the response of the first request and finds the `CSRF` token. That's a _cross site request forgery_ token for security, and not Perl-specific.)